# VBA vector output returning 0

Tags: arrays, vba, vector

I'm trying to brush up a little on my VBA skills and I got stuck on arrays. I have the very simple code below, that takes in a few numbers in a vector, multiply with two and the return the numbers. But the cells are all 0? In locals the calculations are right, and the TestVector is populated correctly, so what seems to be the problem?

```
Function test(Vec)
    n = Vec.Rows.Count
    Dim TestVector
    ReDim TestVector(n, 1)

    For i = 1 To n
        A = Vec(i) * 2
        TestVector(i, 1) = A
    Next i

    test = TestVector
End Function
```

Comment: If you want to brush up on your VBA -- perhaps you can start by adding `Option Explicit` to the top of your code modules (do it once and for all by selecting `Require Variable Declarations` in the VBA editor options). In any event -- how are you *calling* this code?

Comment: I have three numbers in cell A1 to A3. In cell B1 to B3 I have "{=test(A1:A3)}"

Comment: Even if I use the function on a single number, I still get 0

Comment: Unless you are using the highly not-recommended  `Option Base 1`, there is no reason to think that this code would work. `ReDim TestVector(n,1)` is the same as `ReDim TestVector(0 to n, 0 to 1)` but you probably want `(1 to n, 1 to 1)`

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem! I had originally copied the "general" code from an old exam, where our professor always used `Option Base 1`. I hadn't thought that could have been the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA arrays are 0-based as a default. It is possible to override this by using `Option Base 1` at the top of the module, but that is generally frowned upon among VBA programmers. Instead: just declare the lower bounds:

```
ReDim TestVector(1 To n, 1 To 1)
```

Then your code will work as intended.

Even though `Option Base 1` is probably not a good idea, using `Option Explicit` is an extremely good idea. It will save you a great deal of debugging time. You can do this once and for all by enabling `Require Variable Declarations` in the VBA editor options.

Comment: Thank you once again! True, I should be better at declaring variables. Most of my general VBA knowledge is from this one professor that never declared anything, so it's just a bad habit that I have to get rid of.